# Can Hazus tables be downloaded into table or Excel format?

Tags: hazus

Can a Hazus user download results in table format to be sent to a user who does not have Hazus on their ArcMap?

Comment: Do you have HAZUS on your machine?  If so, have you tried exporting a table of results from it to Excel?

Comment: I don't. You only have full access to the data sets if you are in the US, and I am not, so I am hoping someone can send me the tables and I can just use that for my analysis :)

Comment: Have you identified someone that you can ask to do that?  If not, the GIS Chat Room (once you have a reputation of 20+) may be a place to ask. If HAZUS is/has an ArcGIS Desktop extension I would expect that it is a given that export of its tables to Excel is possible.

Comment: (workaround use a VPN for a US IP?)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can't use the program bc I don't have access to Arc 10.4 (and I'm a poor student)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a HAZUS user, or in the US, but if HAZUS is/has an ArcGIS Desktop extension I would expect that it is a given that export of its tables to Excel is possible.